# Django Celery How to run function every 5 sec?

Tags: python, django

I want the function update() to run every 5 seconds. In this case, my function just prints a message to the console. For this I decided to use celery.

I put the following code in a file settings.py and nothing happens when the server runs. What am I missing? Some code perhaps?

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    'add-every-monday-morning': {
        'task': 'accounts.views.update',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you started a worker?

Comment: @GProst, no, I haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually start a celery worker which will execute tasks:

```py
celery -A my_project worker -l info
```

More info here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html